# How to pause a moving AnimatedPositioned in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

As title, Thanks. I only can add a "onEnd" callback, but I can't pause the running animation.

Comment: you cannot do that, for this you need https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PositionedTransition-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is no direct possibility for pausing the running animation. I am pretty sure you can achieve the designated behaviour anyway.

Define two variables:

```
  // Value
  double _animatedPositionedTopValue = 0.0;
  
  // Check if the Animation has already been paused to allow using the "onEnd" multiple times
  bool _animationAlreadyPaused = false;
```

Next build the Animated Positioned Widget (inside of a Stack):

```
         AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            top: _animatedPositionedTopValue,
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 40,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          )
```

Furthermore, you need a trigger for the Animation. It will be a RaisedButton in this case:

```
        RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                // Note that this should be the value at which you want to pause the animation
                _animatedPositionedTopValue = 100.0;
              });
            },
          )
```

To realise the actual logic you of course need the "onEnd" callback which you will simply use as checkpoint for your first animation to complete:

```
                onEnd: () {
                    if (!_animationAlreadyPaused) {
                      _asyncPauseAndContinueAnimation();
                    }
                  }
```

And finally you want to implement the logic for _asyncPauseAndContinueAnimation(), which will basically start a second animation after some time. You can then animate to the final position and it will look like there has been a pause even though you technically ran two animations on the AnimatedPositioned:

```
void _asyncPauseAndContinueAnimation() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    setState(() {
      _animatedPositionedTopValue = 200.0;
      _animationAlreadyPaused = true;
    });
  }
```

This is the full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PauseAnimatedPositioned extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PauseAnimatedPositionedState createState() =>
      _PauseAnimatedPositionedState();
}

class _PauseAnimatedPositionedState extends State<PauseAnimatedPositioned> {
  // Value
  double _animatedPositionedTopValue = 0.0;

  // Check if the Animation has already been paused to allow using the "onEnd" multiple times
  bool _animationAlreadyPaused = false;

  void _asyncPauseAndContinueAnimation() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    setState(() {
      _animatedPositionedTopValue = 200.0;
      _animationAlreadyPaused = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                AnimatedPositioned(
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  top: _animatedPositionedTopValue,
                  onEnd: () {
                    if (!_animationAlreadyPaused) {
                      _asyncPauseAndContinueAnimation();
                    }
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 80,
                    width: 80,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                // Note that this should be the value at which you want to pause the animation
                _animatedPositionedTopValue = 100.0;
              });
            },
            child: Text('Start animation!'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```